# How to correctly version control (svn:ignore) a Java project (Maven, Spring)?

Tags: java, svn, spring, maven, ignore

i was on a 2-day training introducing as to Java EE. We used there Java EE, Spring Framework, Maven, Springsource Tool Suite (Eclipse), Tomcat.

I took the Eclipse workspace we created there and run it on my work PC. I had, if i remember correctly, only to configure Tomcat properly, and it worked on my PC.

Now i want to save the created Eclipse workspace containing 5 "sub"-projects in subversion so that my work colleagues can checkout this to them and run it on their computers.

How to do this correctly? I found somewhere a svn:ignore rule:

```
.classpath
.project
.settings
target
```

Using tortoiseSVN i added to the folder with the workspace this ignore rule, but the found out that the underlying folders target were'nt deleted so i deleted them manually and "added to ignore list". But after that the project in spring source tool suite does not see the mevan dependencies (i think so) because the imports are broken. STS underlines org. in the imports and says it can not resolve this.

How do i correctly version control such a project?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In my project we are using Maven and Eclipse (Helios, currently) and the Maven plugins for Eclipse:

Maven Integration for Eclipse
Maven Integration for WTP

We only have the pom.xml file and the src/ directory tree in our version control system. We make sure *not* to add the eclipse files there. Then when a new developer starts in the project they do Import -> Maven -> Existing Maven Projects. The Maven plugins for Eclipse then set up perfect build paths, settings and so on.

This way it is also very easy to re-import your projects into Eclipse as needed.

So, my tip is to leave the Eclipse files out of SVN and make sure you can setup the project correctly automatically simply by importing a Maven project.

Comment: I tried this approch and it seems mostly ok apart from one thing: i added to my project a spring bean and STS added the Spring Bean Configuration File (SpringBeans.xml) to the _/src_ directory. The project would not compile unless i right click  the src folder  and choose  **Build Path -> Use as source folder** which added a line to the .classpath. So has .classpath to be versioned or should the spring beans config file go elsewhere and where?

Comment: Try putting your SpringBeans.xml in src/main/resources. That will be part of the build path by default using Maven.

Comment: I dont have this folder. I had created a maven project using Maven Quick Start Archteype. Do i have to create this folder manually or should it be created by STS?

Comment: Hi, i dont have a resources folder. I have used the Maven Quickstart Archetype for my project which does not create a resources folder. How do i add it correctly manually. I guess somehow through pom.xml so that it's not in .classpath stored.

Comment: OK i created manually z new source folder. Maven has a default resource folder path meaning : src/main/resources. Now i can version control only pom.xml and src folder. I think i can now safe accept this answer.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your problem the right way, you need to configure Eclipse in order to be able to launch tomcat from it. The key, here, is not maven anymore, but Eclipse, I think. As you've made modifications in your workspace that can't be put in your maven configuration file (the pom.xml), you become "Eclipse dependant".

The key here is that, as you're Eclipse dependant, you need the Eclipse configuration files to work. Consequently, I'm afraid you need to add back `.classpath`, `.project`, `.settings` to your versioning tool... It's not generic, because you force people who work on your project to use Eclipse. But if everybody in your team do so, it shouldn't be a problem.

As I don't use Eclipse anymore, I don't know if versioning theses files can lead to problems. However, I hope this answer will help you to configure your project back...

EDIT : to be more accurate... and maybe give a better answer.

When using  a version control system, the main goal is often (always ?) to give all the keys to use the sources, and develop from them. Consequently, you need to put in your VCS your sources, and all the configurations needed to use them efficiently.

In your specific case, the key is that you've become Eclipse dependant through its Springsource Tool Suite plugin. Consequently, it becomes essential to add the configuration files for this tool, because they can't work without them, and if they can't work, you can't work.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I hope im not Eclipse dependant and i dont want to be. We were told on the training that using Maven makes us IDE independent. But i forgot to ask how to version control such a project. Now im trying it and cant do, so im asking here.

Comment: It's one of the greatest role of maven in most of the projects who use it, I think. The dependency to Eclipse could have been created through the STS, however... I think so, indeed, because your problems appeared when you deleted the Eclipse conf files... It's logical in some ways, because the way you run tomcat (If i've understood correctly, I'm not a JEE specialist) is directly linked to STS and Eclipse. But I may be wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I can tell you my way of subversioning maven eclipse projects. **First**, when you create the project structure you have to **commit** the **.setting, .classpath, .project** files into the subversion repository. If you can't do this the other colleagues will can not use the project structure after checkout. After you commit the project structure, the best way is not to commit these files except only when you change something important eclipse or build path settings, because the others will have conflicts due to the system dependent informations. **Never commit the maven target directory**. Sorry for my english. Hope it helps.

Comment: Actually you don't need the .settings, .classpath or .project while sharing a maven project. If you import the project into Eclipse as a Maven projec, then these files will be automatically generated.

Comment: But in case of using subclipse for checkout, the eclipse automatically opens the project which not the same as import existing maven project. So if you want to checkout the project with eclipse, I think these files have to be committed.

Comment: Hm, tricky. I think I prefer checking out the project using a separate SVN application (e.g. TortoiseSVN if you are using Windows) and then importing the project as a Maven project in Eclipse. You still get access to the Subclipse functionality, just not for the initial checkout and you gain the advantage of not having to version manage your project files. But, yes, somewhat of a drawback.